# PhoneGap Cordova error Windows 10

Tags: windows, cordova

I am trying to use phoneGap for mobileapp but cordova throws error on any command and even -v on Windows 10

> ```
> c:\cordova -v
>
> module.js:340
>     throw err;
>           ^
> Error: Cannot find module 'proto-list'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>     at require (module.js:380:17)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Damjan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:1:79)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar error twice in W10, but you can try the following
1) Run as administrator CMD
2) Copy all your files located in WWW and add a new project.
That has worked for me, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 10 the command

```
c:\cordova -v
```

return

```
5.3.3
```

Have you upgrade  your stack to :

- cordova 5.3.3
- npm 3.3.8
- node 4.2.1
- npm-windows-upgrade 0.4.6

Comment: I solved problem by using cmd directly not node.js cmd like I used on first time